# Substitute type of ReaderT and const through function compostion

Tags: haskell

I am trying to find it out, what is the type of the function composition of `ReaderT` and `const` and want to figure it out by myself.

```
(.) ReaderT const :: ???
```

First, look at the type signature of `ReaderT` and `(.)`:

```
ReaderT :: (r -> m a) -> ReaderT r m a
(.)     :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

then I did following substitution:

```
(.) ReaderT
```

step by step:

```
((r -> m a) -> ReaderT r m a) -> (a1 -> (r -> m a)) -> a1 -> ReaderT r m a
```

it becomes to:

```
(a1 -> r -> m a) -> a1 -> ReaderT r m a
```

next substitute with `const`:

```
const :: (a  -> ( b -> a  ))
         (a1 -> ( r -> m a)) -> a1 -> ReaderT r m a
```

My brain stop at this point. How to continue the type substitution?

Comment: `(r -> m a) ~ b` and `ReaderT r m a ~ c` in `(.)` type when applied to `ReaderT`.

Comment: Why is `(r -> m a)` ~ b and where is the type variable `a` of `const` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReaderT` is an unary function: it takes `(r -> m a)` as its argument and returns `ReaderT r m a` as result.

The first argument of `(.)` is also an unary function `b -> c`. Passing `ReaderT` as its first argument naturally gives `(r -> m a) ~ b` and `ReaderT r m a ~ c`:

```
(r -> m a) -> ReaderT r m a
    b      ->        c
```

So, substituting it into `(.)` type we get

```
> :t (.) ReaderT
(.) ReaderT :: (a -> r -> m a1) -> a -> ReaderT r m a1
```

The `(.)` got passed first argument of two, so now it is an unary function (rougly speaking, the `(a -> b) -> a -> c` part of `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`), where `b` and `c` are fixed to what we wrote above.

Now, `const :: a -> b -> a`, a binary function and exactly what `(.) ReaderT` expects next:

```
(a -> r -> m a1)
 a -> b -> a
```

This means that `a ~ m a1` and due to this `a` in `(.)` type gets turned into `m a`.

So, we passed both arguments to `(.)` and it gives us `a -> c` where `a ~ m a` (note that these a's are different!) and `c ~ ReaderT b m a`.

Comment: What is going to happen with `a` in `(a -> r -> m a1)`?

Comment: Because `const :: a -> b -> a` and we passing it in place of `(a -> r -> m a1)`, the type system infers the fact that `a ~ m a1` in the latter signature.

Comment: Can I say `m a1 -> r -> m a1`?

Comment: Yes, you can say that.